show that $P_* \pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ is exactly the given normal group
I was trying to understand this problem:
Let $a$ and $b$ be the generators of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ corresponding to the two $S^1$ summands. Draw a picture of the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ corresponding to the normal subgroup generated by $a^2, b^2,$ and $(ab)^4,$ and prove that this covering space is indeed the correct one.
I drew it just like what is drawn here How exactly does one construct a covering space corresponding to a subgroup and I know that the normal subgroup N generated by the given generators is contained in $P_* \pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ from the drawing as the loops adjacent to the basepoint(my basepoint was the first vertex at the bottom) corresponds to $a^2$ and $b^2$ and the loops tracing the outer edges of the graph corresponds to $(ab)^4.$ But then I want to show that $P_* \pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ is exactly this normal group. I thought that I should choose a maximal tree and then take all of the conjugates but I do not know how to take all of the conjugated for example if I choose the maximal tree to be the loop tracing the outer edges (minus an edge) of the graph given in the link above, Also, I was told that there are nine conjugates, why is that?
And finally which theorem in Hatcher told us to do this?
Edit:
1-I am also confused should I show that $P_* \pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ contains $N$ or just $\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ contains $N$? I also do not understand why maximal symmetry give us a normal subgroup. I believe we are using Prop. 1.39 on pg. 71.
2-I am also not sure, is $P_* \pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ always injective?
3- Is any deck covering transformation normal?
4- I also found the following statement "Since p_∗ is injective, it suffices to show that \pi_1(X) is generated by conjugates of $a^2, b^2, (ab)^4$" But I do not know which theorem said this and why it is true, could someone clarify this to me please?
Edit:
I knew why we have 9 conjugates.

I'd recommend having a look at Theorem 1.38 in Hatcher. This is known as the classification of covering spaces, or sometimes the Galois correspondence for covering spaces.

I looked at it, so the first one in 1 is the correct expression, thanks for pointing this out. How about my remaining questions?@JD1874

This will be too long to give in a comment so I will write it here. Throughout, let $X=S^1 \vee S^1$.

N is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ and the aim of the question is to show that $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0))=N$.

Yes, this is Proposition 1.31 in Hatcher.

Not in general. You need only take a non-normal subgroup of the fundamental group and construct its associated covering space.

This is part of the content of Theorem 1.38 in Hatcher. After forgetting basepoints, the classification gives a bijection between covering spaces up to isomorphism and subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$ up to conjugacy. This means that once you know that certain elements generate the subgroup up to conjugacy then you're done.



Thank you very much for the help, I think in 2 you meant to say 1.39, am I correct?

I do mean 1.31. It explicitly states that the induced map on $\pi_1$ of a covering map is injective.

Thank you very much!
